# Was there any "official" word on the Inkheart film trilogy?

Tags: movie, inkheart-trilogy

The Inkheart trilogy was pretty popular in the early 2000's, at popular enough that the author, Cornelia Funke, sold the film rights to all three books to New Line Cinema.

The first book was adapted and a film was released in 2008. It was barely a financial success ([making $62M on a $60M budget](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/release/rl4116416001/)). It was not well received critically, with a [39% on Rotten Tomatoes](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/inkheart) and [49 on Metacritic](https://www.metacritic.com/movie/inkheart). However, it did seem to have an all-star cast of Brendan Fraser, Helen Mirren, Paul Bettany, and Andy Serkis, among others. We have seen other film series get pushed through even if the first on was not well received... it all has to do with contracts I would assume...

In my searches I have not found any "official" reason  why the two remaining titles in the trilogy were not produced. I can speculate it was because of the aforementioned poor performance and reviews, or that it might have been the lead actor's, Brendan Fraser, star power fading (along with troubles in his personal life).

**So, what I am asking for is if a statement from a producer, director, or similar position of authority in the studio as to why the sequels were not adapted was made?** (even though the rights had been secured
I understand films rights get secured all the time without anything ever coming of it)

Comment: $62m against a budget of $60m means that it was a big flop. Film budgets *including marketing* are usual about 150% of the cost of making it.

Comment: Note that the rights to *all of the books* would have been secured for two reasons; So that a sequel could be made if the first one was successful and so that no-one else can make a sequel set in the same fictional universe.

Comment: @Valorum are the listed values on Box Office Mojo are the pure filming budgets? Devoid of all marketing?

Comment: @Jontia - Yes. They're usually the estimated cost based on the known number of days of filming, known actor salaries and known director/crew salaries. Because marketing is often bought in advance, with the actual film being irrelevant to the marketing (for example, Universal might buy a billion dollars worth of billboards at the start of the year, irrespective of what films they got coming out), it's always difficult to know what the *actual* marketing spend was, not least because the studio might not actually know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have confirmation from the author that, as of 2016, there were **no plans to make a sequel.**

> **Q.** *Hi, I know your book for the first time from film based on your book "Inkheart", and I've just finished your second book " Inkspell. My question is do you plan to make film based on your second book too? Or you have done?*
>
> **Cornelia Funke:** *No, there are no plans and I admit I am quite glad about it, as the first film was so different from the book. It taught me that turning a novel into a movie is like turning a carpet into a handkerchief:)*
>
> <sub><sup>[Goodreads: Cornelia Funke Answers Your Questions](https://www.goodreads.com/questions/657284-hi-i-know-your-book-for-the-first-time)</sup></sub>

---

As to *why* (actors and producers rarely like talking about sequels that didn't get made because of poor audience response), we do know a few things from [interviews](http://www.snitchseeker.com/harry-potter-news/exclusive-snitchseeker-interviews-inkheart-cast-and-crew-61803/) that were given during the marketing phase of Inkheart.

- **Screenplays were written for the sequels.**

> *We also learned that screenplays have already been written for the two sequels in the Inkworld series – Inkspell and Inkdeath*...

- **The cast and main were contracted to do the sequels**

> ...*and the director and cast members confirmed to us that they are all signed on to do them*...

- **But that this was pursuant to the film doing well (which it did not).**

> ...*assuming Inkheart does well at the U.S. box office.*

---

The film cost an estimated $69M to make and only netted a paltry $62M at the box office (of which a pitful $17M was from US domestic audiences). Factoring in the cost of the marketing and advertising (probably another $30-50M) and cast tour (probably another $10-15M), the film would have been considered by the studio to be a [resounding flop](https://bombreport.com/yearly-breakdowns/2009-2/inkheart/), and killed the franchise.

Comment: I am hazy on the details, but I recall be confused by how the ending of the film different from the ending of the book in ways that broke the continuation of the plot. The film felt like it wasnt supposed to have a sequel, and definitely not one based on the second book.